# PHP filemtime causes page to be blank

Tags: php

I've run this similar function before, but on my new server (PHP 5) `filemtime` doesn't seem to work.

I've tried this little script and the page returns blank. Nothing shows up, not even the echoed out text. It's got to be something within PHP, but can't seem to pinpoint it. Any help is appreciated.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$images = glob("source_images/*.jpg");

usort($images, function($a, $b) {
     return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

echo "worked";
```

The above is just a portion of the code, but I believe the failure is in the `filemtime` because in the above, I don't get get the `echo worked` to show up.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script and refresh it. Does it output any error?

Comment: @AmalMurali, no it doesn't.

Comment: echo something before the loop... if you get output, you know where the problem is?

Comment: @mjayt even echoing something before doesn't return anything. Still blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's because you're not outputting anything. [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) will sort your `$images` array according to the file modification date, but to display the result, you'll have to use a loop:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Update:**

It's unclear what version of PHP you're using but I think this might be because your server doesn't support anonymous functions. Anonymous functions are only available since  PHP 5.4. So, if you try to use on previous PHP versions, it won't work.

Either upgrade to a PHP version that supports anonymous functions, or write  the function separately as below:

```
function timesort($a, $b) {
     return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
}
usort($images, 'timesort');
```

Comment: I've used the same code above and it worked fine. Even if I'm not technically outputting anything, shouldn't the `echo` work? Nothing shows up on the page. I'm not trying to output anything. I'm just trying to sort them. The above is just a short part of the code.

Comment: @Jako: What do you mean `worked fine`? What happens when you create a page with just the code in your question (of course with the `<?php`)?

Comment: My full code sorts the images, then I slice them, and run it through foreach and output the result. I think this server has an issue with the `filemtime`. Because when I upload the above. I don't get  the `echo worked` as an output. Just a blank page with nothing on it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in using a lambda function which is not in PHP 5.1

Answer (score 0):

strange... echo "worked" should be print. When it's not printed usually it is because there is a fatal somewhere. Prolly on glob or filemmtime. Anyway I always used ini_set('display_errors', '1'); with '1' not 1.